# Encrypted User Directory on FreeBSD?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, encryption

I'm running FreeBSD and I'd like to have user's files stored encrypted using his/her password, and have seamless SSH access to those files as well (provided that the user always uses password-based authentication).

In Ubuntu this exact process is possible with [Encrypted Home Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome).

Is it possible in FreeBSD?

Tried pefs but couldn't get it to fetch the password from ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Freebsd has a kernel module, pefs, that can perform filesystem (directory) encryption. http://www.bsdnow.tv/tutorials/pefs has a tutorial on encrypting a user's home directory and tying that to PAM at login.

Comment: `pefs` currently doesn't work with SSH PAM auth